# Terraform Script creating resources successfully but ending with error

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-container-registry, terraform0.12+

I am trying to create the azure container registry using the terraform script . It is creating the resource successfully , but ending with error. Below is my script:-

```
resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
name                     = var.container_registry_name
resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg1.name
location                 = var.deploy_location
sku                      = var.basic_conf["sku_type"]
admin_enabled            = var.basic_conf["admin_enabled"]
provider = azurerm.DeploySub1
}
```

and error we got is this :-
The Terraform Plan has noted changes to be made. (exit code 2)
As this is the Deploy Stage, we will now exit with error.
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Terraform Confirm Plan Deployed

Comment: What command are you running there? Is it running in a pipeline or locally?

Comment: it is running in azure pipeline.